# .NET - Get protocol, host, and port

Tags: .net, asp.net, url, uri, authority

Is there a simple way in .NET to quickly get the current protocol, host, and port? For example, if I'm on the following URL:

`http://www.mywebsite.com:80/pages/page1.aspx`

I need to return:

`http://www.mywebsite.com:80`

I know I can use `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to get the complete URL, and I know I can use `Request.Url.Authority` to get the host and port, but I'm not sure of the best way to get the protocol without parsing out the URL string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See my answer to a simlar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1534478/98740

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The following (C#) code should do the trick

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com:80/pages/page1.aspx");
string requested = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port;
```

Comment: Or string requested = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Authority;

Comment: This is arguably the wrong answer as it will insert a ":" even when there is no port. Use `Uri.GetLeftPart` as @dthrasher points out

Comment: Note that in some cases, you still want to concatenate with uri.Headers["Host"] instead of GetLeftPart(), e.g. behind a proxy your service may be listening on a different/non-standard port and if you use that url in a callback (with the private port) the host will be unreachable.

Comment: There is no need to worry about not having a port number with this solution. Microsoft says "If a port is not specified as part of the URI, the Port property returns the default value for the protocol." / https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.port?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 469):

Even though @Rick has the accepted answer for this question, there's actually a shorter way to do this, using the poorly named [`Uri.GetLeftPart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.getleftpart) method.

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com:80/pages/page1.aspx");
string output = url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

There is one catch to `GetLeftPart()`, however. If the port is the default port for the scheme, it will strip it out. Since port 80 is the default port for http, the output of `GetLeftPart()` in my example above will be `http://www.mywebsite.com`.

If the port number had been something other than 80, it would be included in the result.

Comment: This is the best example in my opinion. It works for localhost:port and live instances.

Comment: GetLeftPart - really, OMG nice naming.

Comment: Does anyone know if this part of the url has a common used name? In JavaScript it's called Origin, but I'm not sure if that's universally agreed on: http://serverfault.com/questions/757494/is-origin-the-common-agreed-name-for-protocol-hostname-port

Comment: Microsoft uses the term "Authority" for this, but I don't know if that's a standard term. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142910/whats-the-difference-between-uri-host-and-uri-authority

Comment: GetLeftPart probably best solution for initial problem, just be careful source of the Uri, if its ASP .Net Request object it may have overridden URL in cluster environment. In my case it was missing port after deployment. Solution can be extension method from [FunnelWeb source code](https://bitbucket.org/TheBlueSky/funnelweb/src/b64c74f361d3/src/FunnelWeb/Utilities/HttpRequestExtensions.cs)

Comment: I personally do not like using the `Uri` class this way. There are a multitude of cases where this constructor will throw an exception. For most cases, I prefer my code to be a little more forgiving before aborting the task at hand.

Comment: to get the rightParts(that's what i think :) )  `var query = url.PathAndQuery;`

Answer (score 70):

Well if you are doing this in Asp.Net or have access to HttpContext.Current.Request
I'd say these are easier and more general ways of getting them:

```
var scheme = Request.Url.Scheme; // will get http, https, etc.
var host = Request.Url.Host; // will get www.mywebsite.com
var port = Request.Url.Port; // will get the port
var path = Request.Url.AbsolutePath; // should get the /pages/page1.aspx part, can't remember if it only get pages/page1.aspx
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I prefer this method, I can get just the peice I want and don't have to worry about whether or not the string is well formed enough to get the port. +1

Comment: Some more details on these properties: http://blog.jonschneider.com/2014/10/systemuri-net-framework-45-visual-guide.html

Answer (score 39):

A more structured way to get this is to use UriBuilder. This avoids direct string manipulation.

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Port);
```

Answer (score 26):

Even shorter way, may require newer ASP.Net:

```cs
string authority = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer,UriFormat.Unescaped)
```

The UriComponents enum lets you specify which component(s) of the URI you want to include.

Comment: Great, because it works in PCL (.GetLeftPart() istn't available there)

Answer (score 24):

Request.Url will return you the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) of the request.  Once you have that, you can retrieve pretty much anything you want.  To get the protocol, call the [Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx) property.

Sample:

```
Uri url = Request.Url;
string protocol = url.Scheme;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

Very similar to Holger's answer. If you need to grab the URL can do something like:

```
Uri uri = Context.Request.Url;         
var scheme = uri.Scheme // returns http, https
var scheme2 = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter; // returns http://, https://
var host = uri.Host; // return www.mywebsite.com
var port = uri.Port; // returns port number
```

The [Uri class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) provides a whole range of methods, many which I have not listed.

In my instance, I needed to grab `LocalHost` along with the `Port Number`, so this is what I did:

```
var Uri uri = Context.Request.Url;
var host = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port;
```

Which successfully grabbed: `http://localhost:12345`

Answer (score 1):

The [`Uri` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri#constructors) has a constructor that "Initializes a new instance of the Uri class based on the specified base URI and relative URI string", thus:

```
var hostPortOnlyUrl = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, "/");
```

Given `Request.RequestUri` in [System.Web.Http Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http?view=aspnet-webapi-5.2), [ApiController.Request Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.request?view=aspnet-webapi-5.2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com:80/pages/page1.aspx");
string requested = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Authority;
```

works to get

https://www.mywebsite.com:80

Comment: What does this add to Rick's accepted 2008 answer?

Answer (score 0):

in my case i use this

```
Request.Url.ToString().Remove(Request.Url.ToString().Count() - (Request.ServerVariables["URL"].ToString().Count()))
```

where

```
Request.Url.ToString()
```

is return http://www.mywebsite.com:80/pages/page1.aspx

```
Request.ServerVariables["URL"].ToString()
```

is return /pages/page1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net core: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
[document of microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getdisplayurl?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
```

my code

```
var leftPath = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl()).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

or

```
var leftPath = new Uri("http://website.com:80/pages/page1").GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```