# Get URL of ASP.Net Page in code-behind

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net page that will be hosted on a couple different servers, and I want to get the URL of the page (or even better:  the site where the page is hosted) as a string for use in the code-behind.  Any ideas?

Comment: See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567590/asp-net-absolute-path-of-a-url/567632#567632

Comment: detailed answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp/16693496#16693496

Comment: It's funny to see the duplicate links... at the time this was question was asked Stack Overflow was still less than a month old.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Use this:

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

That will get you the full path (including http://...)

Comment: Remember, this will also include the query part (?key=value....)

Comment: This doesn't work if the application is not hosted on the server root but in a directory. If the application is hosted on www.contoso.com/app/ this will return just www.contoso.com

Answer (score 121):

If you want only the scheme and authority part of the request (protocol, host and port) use

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

Comment: An even better solution is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567590/asp-net-absolute-path-of-a-url

Comment: @Kimball I'm not sure concatenating strings together is a better solution.

Answer (score 30):

I am using

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
        VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")
```

Answer (score 13):

I use this in my code in a custom class. Comes in handy for sending out emails like no-reply@example.com 
"no-reply@" + BaseSiteUrl
Works fine on any site.

```
// get a sites base urll ex: example.com
public static string BaseSiteUrl
{
    get
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string baseUrl = context.Request.Url.Authority + context.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
        return baseUrl;
    }

}
```

If you want to use it in codebehind get rid of context.

Comment: Note that `Authority` doesn't include the protocol (`http://` or `https://`).  Was fine in your instance but might not be for some.  Can be obtained through `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme`, though.

Answer (score 8):

Do you want the server name? Or the host name?

[Request.Url.Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96029/get-url-of-aspnet-page-in-code-behind#96052) ala Stephen

[Dns.GetHostName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname.aspx) - Server name

[Request.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx) will have access to most everything you'll need to know about the page being requested.

Answer (score 7):

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.FilePath + "?theme=blue";
```

that will give you the full path to the page you are sitting on.  I added in the querystring.

Answer (score 5):

I'm facing same problem and so far I found:

```
new Uri(Request.Url,Request.ApplicationPath)
```

or

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)+Request.ApplicationPath
```

Answer (score 3):

Request.Url.Host

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include any unique string on the end, similar to example.com?id=99999, then use the following

```
Dim rawUrl As String = Request.RawUrl.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a js file you can capture the following, that can be used in the codebehind as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Server: ' + window.location.hostname);
    alert('Full path: ' + window.location.href);
    alert('Virtual path: ' + window.location.pathname);
    alert('HTTP path: ' + 
        window.location.href.replace(window.location.pathname, ''));    
</script>
```