# newbie .net question - variable that's equivalent of $_SESSION['SERVER_NAME']

Tags: .net, http-host, server-name

I'm still new to .net....I'm trying to find the variable that prints the domain name that an aspx.cs file is currently executing from.  I come from PHP land, and it has $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] or $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].  What's the .net equivalent for those variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have all that in:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

In that object you have the Domain, AbsoluteUri, AbsolutePath, etc. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-url-of-the-current-page-in-c) and [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_properties.aspx) for more references

Answer (score 3):

`Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]` and `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]`