# What's the difference between ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] and ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-host, server-name

I'm confused about the difference between these two server variables. Checking the IIS documentation, it states :-

#### HTTP_HOST

> Returns the name of the Web server.
> This may or may not be the same as
> SERVER_NAME depending on type of name
> resolution you are using on your Web
> server (IP address, host header).

#### SERVER_NAME

> The server's host name, DNS alias, or
> IP address as it would appear in
> self-referencing URLs.

Could someone provide some examples how they can be different?

We have 2 IIS webservers in our web farm .. and each one has 2 websites (identical of course, per server).

For each website has around 5 or so bindings.

So .. what would the values be? what's the difference?

Comment: Realted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710906/newbie-net-question-variable-thats-equivalent-of-sessionserver-name

Answer (score 2):

Just found that enabling tracing in one of IIS hosted aspx page that SERVER_NAME returns just the server name whereas  HTTP_HOST returns servername:port that site runs. to enable trace set

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" Trace="true" %>`

note the Trace value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ASP.NET, but in PHP, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is what the client sent in the HTTP `Host` header, while `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is determined by the webserver configuration.

Comment: so if i hack my hosts file by adding a custom entry that points to another webserver .. and then enter that domain into my browser .. and assuming the target webserver is not restricted by host-headers .. then when I connect, then HTTP_HOST value will be the domain i entered into the browser -> which is my custom one. ???

Comment: Yes. A simpler way to achieve the same is to directly [tamper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) with the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP_HOST`  is HTTP Host Header, can be changed via DNS (add a domain and poit to your server) or just via HOSTS file on your computer.

SERVER_NAME on Windows is  the Machine name. you can see the name (or change it) via Right Click on `My Computer` (or Computer on Win10+), and Properties.