# Taking params from a url

Tags: c#, url

Take these two URLs:

1. www.mySite.com?name=ssride360
2. www.mySite.com/ssride360

I know that to get the `name` param from url 1 you would do:

`string name = Request.Params['name'];`

But **how would I get that for the second url?**

I was thinking about attempting to copy the url and remove the known information (www.mySite.com) and then from there I could set `name` to the remainder.

**How would I do a url copy like that? Is there a better way to get 'ssride360' from the second url?**

**Edit** Looking on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-url-of-the-current-page-in-c) I found some info on copying URLs

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /TESTERS/Default6.aspx
```

Is this the best way for me? each url have one additional param (mySite.com/ssride360?site=SO) for example. Also I know that mySite.com/ssride360 would reference a folder in my project so wouldn't i be getting that file along with it (mySite.com/ssride360/Default6.aspx)?

At this point I think there are better ways then a url copy.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Uri x = new Uri("http://www.mySite.com/ssride360");
 Console.WriteLine (x.AbsolutePath);
```

prints `/ssride360`

Answer (score 1):

This method will allow you to get the name even if there is something after it.  It is also a good model to use if you plan on putting other stuff after the name and want to get those values.

```
        char [] delim = new char[] {'/'};
        string url = "www.mySite.com/ssride360";
        string name = url.Split(delim)[1];
```

Then if you had a URL that included an ID after the name you could do:

```
        char [] delim = new char[] {'/'};
        string url = "www.mySite.com/ssride360/abc1234";
        string name = url.Split(delim)[1];
        string id = url.Split(delim)[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting is a common solution for this problem. You give it the patterns of the URL's you want to match and what it needs to change it into. So it would detect www.mySite.com/ssride360 and transform it into www.mySite.com?name=ssride360. The user of the website sees the original URL and doesn't know anything changed, but your code sees the transformed URL so you can access the variables in the normal way. Another big plus is that the rules allow you to set the patterns that get transformed as well as the ones that just get passed through to actual folders / files.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score -2):

Like javascript?  If so...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getName() {
    var urlParts = window.location.pathname.split('/');  //split the URL.
    return urlParts[1];    //get the value to the right of the '/'.
}
</script>
```

Comment: This question is inherently dealing w/ web development, regardless of tags.  Any code dealing w/ URLs likely exists on a web page.  Abe Miessler's answer is the same thing.  Would it make you feel better if I removed the word javascript?

Comment: My answer is in C# which is what the question asks for.  Even if you remove the word javascript it will still be javascript and not C#.  He probably wants to do something on the server side rather than the client side, so using javascript would make things much more difficult.