# How to obtain the current url

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the URL of the current page in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp)

If I am in a page say `http://myweb/folder/obtain.aspx?thevalue=3` , how can i determine if the url contains `obtain.aspx?thevalue` in c#?. I just need to check whether the user landed on this particular page.

PS: I guess I dont really need to check for the `?thevalue` but just the `obtain.aspx`

Comment: @RichardD The answers there do not explain how to get the name of the actual page/file landed on, they just show how to get the Url. Based on title they are the same, but question content makes them different.

Comment: How to do this in python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
//gets the current url
string currentUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

//check the url to see if it contains your value
if (currentUrl.ToLower().Contains("obtain.aspx?thevalue"))
    //do something
```

Comment: +1 as sometimes links are UPPER or Title or lower case.

Comment: what if i have '#' in URL......i.e http://myweb/folder/obtain.aspx#commentfocus

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the exact file name ( obtain.aspx )
Request.Url.Segments[1]

Comment: In my case it's the last segment which is 3. How would I modify the above to get the end of the URL (the last part after /)?

Answer (score 1):

`Request.Url` should contain everything you need. In your case, you could use something like

```
if( Request.Url.PathAndQuery.IndexOf("obtain.aspx") >= 0 )...
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Request.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx). To get the exact file name, you may try also using [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)

```
var aspxFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.LocalPath);
var landed = aspxFile.Equals("obtain.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
if(landed) { // your code }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Url` will return the exact Uri being requested by the user.

If you want to check specifically for `thevalue`, you're probably better off looking for that in [`Request.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

it's ugly but you cand try

```
if (HttpContext.Current.HttpRequest.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("/obtain.aspx"))
 // then do something
```

Comment: Contains will give a true for "2obtain.aspx" aswell... Equals() should be used & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.LocalPath);