# How to get Current Page's Url in asp.net using code behind technique?

Tags: asp.net, url

I want to get Url of the page like abc.aspx. how can i get this using code behind technique. Any idea.?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Full Details, you can later use string Operations for advanced manipulation:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
// localhost
```

[How to get the URL of the current page in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'd like to point out that using absolute uri will also grab the query string if one is present.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Request.RawUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx):

> Gets the raw URL of the current request.

Answer (score 3):

`Request.RawUrl` property gives you the fully qualified URL of your current page

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current page url as Canonical tag using below way....
Here we are setting exact page url with dynamic Hostname.

for example : if you want to set canonical tag :
*http://www.TestWorld.co.uk/about*

In below code, Hostname will come dynamic as *http://www.TestWorld.co.uk/* and Request.RawUrl will give result *about*, ultimately we can get purely dynamic canonical url. 
Note : Here Canonical tag will create dynamically on html page, you not need to create it manually.

```
HtmlLink canonical = new HtmlLink();
var uri = Request.Url;
string hostName = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
canonical.Href = hostName + Request.RawUrl.ToString();
canonical.Attributes["rel"] = "canonical";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(canonical);
```