# Getting URL of current page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to check if the current URL of the page contains a specific string or not. Now, I know you can do this by `ClientQueryString.Contains`. However, the page that I have to modify already inherit `System.Web.UI.UserControl` And I know in order to use `ClientQueryString.Contains` you must inherit `System.Web.UI.Page`

Is there anyway around this or another method that I can use since I can't inherit something else?

Comment: Whats wrong with `Request.Url`? Use `Dim CurrentURL As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Current Page's Url in asp.net using code behind technique?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139238/how-to-get-current-pages-url-in-asp-net-using-code-behind-technique)

Comment: Duplicate depends on what part of the URL the asker is seeking to examine. The link does not include `Request.QueryString` which was the requirement in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a full set of examples for `Request.Url` [at this site](http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/Using_RequestUrl_to_find_specific_parts_of_the_web_pages_address)
To isolate the querystring you can do:
`Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Query, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped)`
Or 
`Request.QueryString` which is my assumption of what you're trying to do from your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following to get different parts of `URL`

**EXAMPLE** (Sample URL)

`http://localhost:60527/MyWeb/Default2.aspx?QueryString1=1&QuerrString2=2`

**CODE**

```
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
localhost
localhost:60527
/MyWeb/Default2.aspx
/MyWeb
http://localhost:60527/MyWeb/Default2.aspx?QueryString1=1&QuerrString2=2
/MyWeb/Default2.aspx?QueryString1=1&QuerrString2=2
```

You can copy paste above sample code & run it in asp.net web form application with different URL.

[See here for more Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use HttpRequest.Url?

[Request.URL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)