# Get the current URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to set a variable to the current URL using:

```
Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.url.AbsoluteUri
```

Which is returning:

> http://localhost/xxxxx2015/xxxx.asmx/xxxx

This seems to be the file name followed by the web function name.

What it's supposed to return/what it's displaying in IE is:

> http://localhost/xxxxx2015/Default.aspx?form=xxxx

Why is this?

Comment: Check this answer from Muhammad Omar ElShourbagy:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15002973/3428749

Comment: Are you within a web service when you call this code? Or are you within an ASPX form? Your question lacks context.

Comment: You might try: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString

http://blog.jonschneider.com/2014/10/systemuri-net-framework-45-visual-guide.html

Comment: @NunoRibeiro - I've already looked at his post and it didn't help me.

Comment: @mason - Web Service.

Comment: @SLWS - still returning the same url as above.

Comment: You are expecting Web Form URL to be returned by `HttpContext.Current.Request.url.AbsoluteUri` when you are in context of Web Service ? How's that possible ? Are you making an Ajax call to web service from aspx page and you are trying to get the URL of web form in the web service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently in a WebRequest, so the current request *is* the request for that method. However, it is sent from some page, so possibly a "referrer" is set with the URL you are looking for.

See [Getting the HTTP Referrer in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258217/getting-the-http-referrer-in-asp-net) for more details on how to get it. Basically: use [`Request.UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)