# StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1,

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I use Web api selef host:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Testp([FromBody]string title)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post");
    }
}
```

this is simple controller
and this is my client:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1010");
      const string englishTitle = "TesteDelete";
      var post = client.PostAsync("Test/Testp", new
      {
                    title = englishTitle
                }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
                var result = post.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    string content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                }
```

why my result is:

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Sun, 21 Apr 2013 12:00:03 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 165
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}
```

I thnik my modelbinder has some error

Comment: I noticed you didn't end your base uri with a "/"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd imagine you're debugging using the visual studio web server (down by the clock).  The port  for this can change at any time, so I'm guessing it is no longer '1010' as specified in your URL:

`"http://localhost:1010"`

Perhaps you should [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp) to get the current URL automatically.

Answer (score 7):

I figured out my issue was if I didn't end the base URI with "/"  and tried to pre-pend it to client.PostAsync(.. it wouldn't work. But if I appended to the base uri it would like so,

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new  Uri("https://test.test.com/somepath/") })
 var response = client.PostAsync("Broadcast/Order", content).Result;
```

worked, while:

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.test.com/somepath") })
 var response = client.PostAsync("/Broadcast/Order", content).Result;
```

Does not. Not sure why, but glad I figure it out pretty quick!

Comment: I want to hug you

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using the default routing, it's RESTful (by HTTP verb, rather than RPC, by method name) so you shouldn't be posting to `http://localhost:1010/Test/Testp` but `http://localhost:1010/Test`
2. Your action signature takes a string but you are POSTing an anonymous object instead.
   Your POST should look like this (notice that we're sending just the string):

   `var post = client.PostAsync("Test", englishTitle, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());`

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = URL;
            var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", FRAppConfigKeys.GetValue("ClientId")),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("client_secret", FRAppConfigKeys.GetValue("ClientSecret")),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", FRAppConfigKeys.GetValue("GrantType") ),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", FRAppConfigKeys.GetValue("UserName")),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("password", FRAppConfigKeys.GetValue("Password"))
                }
            );
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, data).Result;
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Dictionary<string, string> tokenDictionary =
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(result);
            string token = tokenDictionary["access_token"];
```

I am facing same problem. But Now resolved. You can use this code. it will really help you.

Comment: I am facing same problem. But Now resolved. You can use this code. it will really  help you.