# Get Current.Request.Url in mvc application having a .aspx extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 application in which I have to map a request with .aspx extension to another route. what i am trying to do is to get the current request url in application start. but the problem is it runs fine with all urls without .aspx extension but in a url for ex
(http://example.com/Products/5/16/Eettafels.aspx) it shows only http://example.com/

however with http://example.com/Products/5/16/Eettafels it shows the correct path ..

All the code is a simple line:

```
string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
```

Can any one have any idea what i am doing wrong

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp

Comment: means you want to redirect to .aspx page url ?

Comment: a kind of so ... its a 301 redirect for seo

Comment: Why did you need to lowercase the Url address again?

Answer (score 16):

though it is a very old post.

I am just pasting the code Ha Doan linked to so that it will be easier to anyone landing on this question.

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /TESTERS/Default6.aspx

string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
// localhost
```

Check this SO for discussion on this

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can override a Controller method that executes before any Action is called. What I'd then suggest is you keep the current Url like @Ifitkhar suggested in a ViewBag, or TempData, in case you intend on redirecting, then using it later in the Action you want to return afterwards.

```
public class ProductsController
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext){
        TempData["previousUrl"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```