# Azure App Services DNS Configuration

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Hy

We have two Azure App Services (WebApps). One is the Web Application (Single Page), the other is the REST Service as the backend.

We own our own domain (say www.blabla.com) and we would like to map our App Services the following way:
- xxx.blabla.com should point to our Web Application
- xxx.blabla.com/api should point to our REST Service

Is this possible on Azure? How can we achieve such a scenario?

Thanks for your help.

Kind regards,
Peter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561105/redirect-multiple-domains-to-same-azure-website-with-custom-parameters

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is typically achieved in On-Premise using a feature called Reverse proxy via URL Rewrite Module.

This Module is available on **Azure Web Apps**. Ruslan has a great article demonstrating this feature:
http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/

You don't require any code for this.