# getting error while trying to get current page url in c# class file

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get current page url in c#. I have tried below code

`_path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;`

but I am getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

please help me in this.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I think this is already answered at another question. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What is `null` here?

Comment: Thank you all. I will go through the provided links

Comment: Is there any other way instead of httpcontext to get the current page?