# VB.NET display label text only on default.aspx page only

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Have a message that currently displays on every page of our website. I'd like to change this so that it only appears on the homepage which is default.aspx. Please let me know what I can try. the below code lives in the code behind of the master page of the site. We use vb.net but if someone can write it in C# I can convert it.

**Previous code that displays label text on every page:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Using ds As DataSet = SystemDataObject.SystemDataGetMessage()
        lblSystemMessage.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("SystemMessage_sd").ToString
End Using   

End Sub
```

**Code I have written that isn't working, what am I missing?**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Using ds As DataSet = SystemDataObject.SystemDataGetMessage()
    Dim appPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
    If appPath = "/Default.aspx" Then
        lblSystemMessage.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("SystemMessage_sd").ToString
    End If
End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using Request.Url and parse it to get "default.aspx" ? Here is another post :in c# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp

Comment: When you navigate to Default.aspx, does the lblSystemMessage.Text line of code get hit?

Comment: Haven't tried using request.url. Not really sure how to do that and not understanding what I'd then do with it? @Seano666 no the lblSystemMessage.Text is getting hit when I step through it.

Comment: Your answer to my question is unclear sorry, the code for setting the label IS getting executed?  So then are you not seeing the label text on the page when it loads?

Comment: Sorry @Seano666 no when I step thru the code the lblSystemMessage.Text is not getting executed, it skips over to the End If.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up wrapping the control in a panel with ID of Message and using the following code to display only if on the homepage.

```
If Page.Title = "Home" Then
    Message.Visible = True
Else
    Message.Visible = False
End If
```