# ExceptionHandling: If controller method returns json then return json, if View then return Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'd want to achieve something like this:

If exception was thrown in method that returns Json then return `new Json(new { success = false, error = "unknown" });`

but if method returns `View` then return `Redirect`

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext ctx)
{
    try
    {
        await next(ctx);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ctx, ex);
    }
}

private static void HandleException(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
{
    // some logger
    LoggerService.Log(ex);

    context.Response.Redirect("/Error/ErrorPage");
}
```

How to determine where request was send? I mean how to get type of method which the request was sent to?

because I'd want to do something like `typeof(targetMethod)` to determine whether it is e.g `JsonResult` or not

Comment: Can't you throw e.g. _JsonException_ or _ViewException_ and then do the proper action?

Comment: @PatiK I wanted to do it globally :P

Comment: @Joelty I guessed that ;) I meant that you could add it in a base code (e.g. similar to logging).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to handle exception thrown by Action method. If that's the case, the ASP.NET Core has a built-in [`IExceptionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iexceptionfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which is suitable for that:

> A filter that runs after an action has thrown an Exception.

To achieve your goal, create a `CustomExceptionFilter`:

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    private ILogger<CustomExceptionFilter> _logger;

    public CustomExceptionFilter(ILogger<CustomExceptionFilter> logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var ex = context.Exception;
        var c = (ControllerActionDescriptor) context.ActionDescriptor;

        if(c == null){
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(500);
        } else if (typeof(JsonResult) == c.MethodInfo.ReturnType) {
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new { success = false, error = "unknown" });
        } else {
            // Redirect
            this._logger.LogCritical(ex,ex.Message);
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Error/ErrorPage");
        }
    }
}
```

and register this filter as below :

```
services.AddMvc(opts => {
    opts.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter));
});
```

it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a bit of reflection here:

```
string methodName = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

var methodInfo = asm.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type)) //filter controllers
    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
    .Where(method => method.IsPublic)
    .Where(x => x.DeclaringType != null)
    .Where(x => x.Name == methodName)
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (methodInfo == null)
{
    return null; // Method wasn't found
}

if (typeof(JsonResult) == methodInfo.ReturnType)
{
    // Return JSON
}
else if (typeof(JsonResult) == methodInfo.ReturnType)
{
    // Redirect
}
else
{
    // Exception handling
}
```

Comment: How do you access ``ControllerContext`` in middleware? I injected it but almost everything's null inside

Comment: My bad, you can't. Try with [How to get the URL of the current page in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/593709/2307070), you'll need to replace `HttpContext.Current` with `context`