# how to get full servername and port running in mvc 2 by codebehind

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

hi every body i have a question

example if i have url : http://localhost:8512/bookuser/Create

how to get "http://localhost:8512" by code behind in mvc2 ??

thanks regard

Answer (score 9):

The following will give you the protocol, host and port part of the request

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

Answer (score 2):

In MVC3, most directly, You can do it like this (should be pretty same):
Within a .cs, You can use code like this:

```
Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
String absoluteUrlBase = String.Format(
    "{0}://{1}{2}{3}"
    uri.Scheme,
    uri.Host,
    (uri.IsDefaultPort
        ? ""
        : String.Format(":{0}", uri.Port));
```

within the a .cshtml, You can use

```
string absoluteUrlBase = String.Format(
    "{0}://{1}{2}{3}"
    Request.Url.Scheme
    Request.Url.Host + 
    (Request.Url.IsDefaultPort
        ? ""
        : String.Format(":{0}", Request.Url.Port));
```

In both cases, the `absoluteUrlBase` will be `http://localhost:8512` or `http://www.contoso.com`.

or You can go through the [VoodooChild's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4731132/1138663) link...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

This contains information about the page being requested.

Also, keep [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96029/get-url-of-asp-net-page-in-code-behind) for future reference

Comment: This isn't quite answering the question because it returns the path portion of the page's URL.

Answer (score -1):

Look for the first "/" after the "http://" - here's a piece of code:

```
public class SName {

    private String  absUrlStr;

    private final static String slash = "/", htMarker = "http://";

    public SName (String s) throws Exception {
            if (s.startsWith (htMarker)) {
                    int slIndex = s.substring(htMarker.length()).indexOf(slash);
                    absUrlStr = (slIndex < 0) ? s : s.substring (0, slIndex + htMarker.length());
            } else {
                    throw new Exception ("[SName] Invalid URL: " + s);
    }}

    public String toString () {
            return "[SName:" + absUrlStr + "]";
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
            try {
                    System.out.println (new SName ("http://localhost:8512/bookuser/Create"));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
}}}
```