# ASP.NET and jQuery: calling a web service from anywhere in the file tree without regard to localhost/prod?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I need the following jQuery call to work from the localhost as well as the production server, but can't figure out how to do this. This is in a master page, and calls can come from various places in the file structure as well. I would certainly appreciate any help.

```
        function getInternetLeadsCount() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:64558/mysite.com/Web_Services/AjaxWebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                success: AjaxSucceeded,
                error: AjaxError
            });
        }

        function AjaxSucceeded(data, status) {
            alert('jQuery: ' + data.d);
        }

        function AjaxError(x, y, z) {
            alert(x + ' ' + y + ' ' + z);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute url:

url: "/Web_Services/AjaxWebService.asmx/HelloWorld"

Comment: I tried that as one of my initial trials and always got 'not found'.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can make webmethod in your aspx page and call that method like this.

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "defaul.aspx/HelloWorld",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
alert(msg.d);
  }
});

OR you can have the absoulte path

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: I'd have to create the web method in each of the pages that needs this, since it's in a master page, which is quite a few.

Comment: you can put $.ajax function in every page or suppose can have the server variable name it pagename. Public string _Pagename{get;set;} put this in master page and set it on every page. now you can make URL like this.     url: "'+ <%=_Pagename%> +'"

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would suggest that you install IIS or IIS Express on your workstation instead of working off of the built-in Visual Studio server. You should always to to develop in an identical environment to your production server. Doing otherwise can cause issues, as you have  noticed.

Apart from that, I would probably use C# to render out a JavaScript variable containing the *true* web root. In your master page or aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webRoot = '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/") %>';
    console.log(webRoot); // '/mysite.com'
</script>
```

On your workstation, `webRoot='/mysite.com'` and on production `webRoot='/'`.
Then you can use the `webRoot` JavaScript variable to build up an application-relative path to your web service.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = webRoot + '/Web_Services/AjaxWebService.asmx/HelloWorld'
    console.log(url); // '/mysite.com/Web_Services/AjaxWebService.asmx/HelloWorld'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked, which came from [Get URL of ASP.Net Page in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96029/get-url-of-asp-net-page-in-code-behind)

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<%= new Uri(Request.Url,Request.ApplicationPath) %>" + "/Web_Services/AjaxWebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{}",
                    success: AjaxSucceeded
                });


            function AjaxSucceeded(data, status) {
                // Do whatever...
            }
```