# how to get current url in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get URL of ASP.Net Page in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96029/get-url-of-asp-net-page-in-code-behind)

I'm trying to hold current url in string in the code behind.

as example this is the current url address:http:www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit
how I can hold this in string variable?

please help me out.

Comment: Its been asked many times, searching first is easier than asking first!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will get you the full URL:

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: What if i have '#' in URL.....                                                                       i.e :http:test.abc.com/sitesposure.aspx#commentfocus.........                   will it work?

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser - No, hash parameters are front end only. If you wish to access this back-end then AJAX is a good option. See my blog post on how to read hash tag values: http://curtistimson.co.uk/js/reading-url-hashtag-values/