# How to get the current URL from ASP.NET code behind

Tags: asp.net

My application is hosted on different servers, and I want to get the URL of the page on the current server.

How can you get this property in code behind?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get URL of ASP.Net Page in code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96029/get-url-of-asp-net-page-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

http://thehost.com/dir/Default.aspx

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
```

/dir/Default.aspx

```
string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

thehost.com

Comment: What if i have '#' in URL.....                                                                       i.e :http:test.abc.com/sitesposure.aspx#commentfocus.........                   will it work?

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser HttpContext.Current.Request.Url returns a System.Uri. Here's a summary of all of the Uri properties: http://blog.jonschneider.com/2014/10/systemuri-net-framework-45-visual-guide.html

Answer (score 9):

Another way to get URL from code behind file

```
public string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath
{
    get
    {
        //Return variable declaration
        var appPath = string.Empty;

        //Getting the current context of HTTP request
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        //Checking the current context content
        if (context != null)
        {
            //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
            appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                                    context.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                    context.Request.Url.Host,
                                    context.Request.Url.Port == 80
                                        ? string.Empty
                                        : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
                                    context.Request.ApplicationPath);
        }

        if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
            appPath += "/";

        return appPath;
    }
}
```

check this [Link](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/get-absolut-url-of-asp-net-application/) you will get more info.

Answer (score 5):

```
string MyUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Answer (score 5):

> string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

Comment: this gave me /dir/Default.aspx. @Siraj solution gave me http://localhost:1872/dir/Default.aspx and that's what i need. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GetApplicationName(){
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    int intStartIndex = GetIndex(url, 3);
    int intEndIndex = GetIndex(url, 4);
    return url.Substring(intStartIndex, (intEndIndex - intStartIndex) - 1);
}

public int GetIndex(string str, int indexNo){
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < indexNo; i++){
        int tempIndex = str.IndexOf("/") + 1;
        str = str.Remove(0, tempIndex);
        index += tempIndex;
    }
    return index;
}
```