# How to find the request sender Url in my controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm using Asp.Net MVC. I want to know the url from which a request has been sent to my controller action.For example my controller action is(Customer/Index) and I want to get the url from which, my action is called.(I don't need the current URL).I want the source URL from which the request sent to me. Is there any solution?

Comment: Why would you need to know the full URL?

Comment: you can use this Request.Url.AbsoluteUri:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get URL of ASP.Net Page in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96029/get-url-of-asp-net-page-in-code-behind)

Comment: @MangeshAuti Please explain why you think that duplicate target is related to this question, because it's not

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto OP want  Request URL and this type of que already asked

Comment: @MangeshAuti Really? You are reading the OP's mind then, because the question says "I want to get the url from which, my action is called"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto then what does it mean ??

Comment: More Explanation: for example if someone send a request from www.SomeSite.com to my website, I want to know the www.SomeSite.com url. Or if the request come from my another controller-action, I want to know that url, Not the current url

Answer (score 1):

You could try using url referrer e.g.

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

```
Request.QueryString["Referrer"].ToString()
```

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer works if the request comes from outside of my website. But I want to know both coming requests from outside an inside my website.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link: [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)

It states that "A Referer header is not sent by browsers if: The referring resource is a local "file" or "data" URI."

If you want to have that available if your page calls 'itself' i.e. another page/controller in you web application, you can try to add the header manually on a per request basis.