# How to get the current URL of the web app>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET web app is deployed into a location like `https://server/path1/path2`.

How can I get in the C# code that path, where the app is running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get URL of ASP.Net Page in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96029/get-url-of-asp-net-page-in-code-behind)

Comment: try `Request.GetDisplayUrl().ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        string baseURL2 = 
         Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.UriEscaped);

        Debug.Print(baseURL2);
```

It does not include a trailing "/"

Edit: sorry, I see this is for MVC, so, I can't suggest if above will work. Above was for webforms.