# Split a string so that it loses http:// and anything after the '.'

Tags: c#, url, split

I need to parse a url so that only my server shows "NA30" However when I'm doing the split I cant seem to just get the na30. I have tried trimming with '.' and '/' and i think I'm just getting the array parts wrong.  Any guidance?

Link
https://na30.salesforce.com

What I'm currently working on

```
    string thisUrl;
    if (Helper.InstanceUrl.Contains(@"://"))
    {
        thisUrl = Helper.InstanceUrl.Split(new[] { "://" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
            return thisUrl.Split('/')[0].Split('.')[0];
    }
    return "";
```

Comment: You already have an answer from the looks of it, but I'm still curious what problem you are having? I tried your code and it returns "na30" for me. The answers here may not be what you need if there's a different issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also find your string with the Uri class

```
Uri u = new Uri("https://na30.salesforce.com");
Console.WriteLine(u.Host.Split('.')[0]);
```

A worth question to read about is [What's the difference between Uri.Host and Uri.Authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142910/whats-the-difference-between-uri-host-and-uri-authority)

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. I was gonna do the exact same thing, even the varialble name...

Comment: Exactly what I needed so much cleaner than what I came up with!! Thanks!

Comment: A little improvement I suggest: check whether it starts with www, if so then return the 1st item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to keep only the first part of the domain.

`Regex.Match(url, @"//([^\.]+)").Groups[1].Value`

http://rextester.com/URF41242

Comment: You don't have to delimit a period inside of a character class.