# IIS rewrite - regular extensions

Tags: iis

I have problem with rewrite and I've been working on it for 2 days.

I need to rewrite from `domaintest.com/ds` to `ds.domaintest.com` (rewrite, not redirect)

I've tried almost every combination of regular expressions and it still doesn't work. Anyone got an idea?

help witch regular extensions

Comment: URL Rewriters cannot change the hostname that serves a request - only a redirection can do that. The next closest thing is making an reverse-proxy request (with IIS ARR), but that won't change the hostname that appears in the user's address-bar.

Comment: _"I've tried almost every combination of regular expressions and it still doesn't work. Anyone got an idea?"_ - I'm curious exactly what regular-expressions you used because it simply isn't possible for a `<rewrite>` rule to rewrite the hostname of a request: the  `<action type="Rewrite" url="{new_url}" />` element only lets you specify a replacement-expression for the request URI's path, [not the request URI's authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142910/whats-the-difference-between-uri-host-and-uri-authority).

Comment: Thank you for your response. It explained a lot.

Comment: `<rule name="ARR_test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^ds(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://ds.domaintest.com/" />
                </rule>`

Comment: That code, as-is, will rewrite to `https://yourwebsite.tld/https%3A//ds.domaintest.com` - and it doesn't do anything that actually enables ARR.