# Request object in Application_Start event

Tags: c#, iis-7

We currently use this line of code to get the current applications url in the Application_Start event.

```
string sApplicationURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" 
                         + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority 
                         + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

I just recently found out that in IIS7.0 the Request object is no longer available when the Application_Start event is fired.

Is there another way to get the current applications url without using the Request object?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at this:
http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx

In summary, the error occurs because the Request context is not longer available to the Application_Start event.  This blog states two choices to deal with this error:

1) Change your code to work w/o Request, or
2) Modify your application to run in Classic Mode (not recommended).

To get the ApplicationPath, use **HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath**.

Comment: you should elaborate instead of posting a bare link to a blog which could be moved

Comment: +1. In addition you can get the other two pieces of information, by implementing a handler for the Application_BeginRequest event.  This is described in the article in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a all-in-one article on all breaking changes including this one,

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis-70/

Yes, its content somehow comes from http://mvolo.com (and the reason is simple).

Comment: All this is useful but is there a way to get the application URL in the Application_Start event?

Comment: Actually no. An ASP.NET website can have multiple bindings, it could run under multiple hosts and multiple port numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243270/how-to-get-full-host-name-port-number-in-application-start-of-global-aspx