# how can i fix my local host addres(port number ) in c# or get my local address in c#?

Tags: c#, localhost

I send a mail which includes activation link. When i open the program , this localhost changes everytime how can i get the address of localhost or fix it?

```
htmlBody = string.Format(" Hi " + userName + "\n Thank you for creating an account with RSS MANAGEMENT SYSTEM \n </ br>" + "Please click the below link to activate your account <br />" + "<a href='http://localhost:2386/ActivateUser.aspx?userName{0}&Id={1}'>Activate {0} </a>", UName, user_name);
```

Comment: WCF \Silverlight \asp.net \asp.net-mvc ... which?

Comment: I'm not sure if you quite grasp the concept of 'localhost'.
The IP address for localhost is *always* 127.0.0.1

Comment: Do you mean the `port`?  You can hard-code that in your development environment in the project settings in Visual Studio.  Or you can publish your application to a staging area which would not have a port number, such as `staging.mydomain.com`.

Comment: @TimothyGroote. He's probably asking about the port.

Comment: @TimothyGroote - I think he means the port on the server - `//localhost:2386`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4243338/266143).

Comment: note: using string.Format but concatenating string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just testing your app is not much of a problem, you can either go to the properties of the project -> web tab -> set the Specific Port to a fixed number => thats it.

Or you can set up the iis and have the app running on a particular virtual directory and avoid the port number at all [Configuring IIS](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html)

But... if you are running on a server to have the app public you will have to go with the second option to have a definitely URl

Comment: how can i find properties of the project I cannot find it . I look at the project tab

Comment: @leventkalay92 Right click on the web project and there it should be the web tab