# Get The Current Application Virtual Path in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

Inside the Application_Start of my Global.asax.cs, I am trying to get the current application path using:

```
var virtualPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
                          + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;
```

This will return for example: `http://localhost:99/MySite/`

I will then use this URL and do the following:

```
var pageToHit = virtualPath + Pages\MyOtherPage.aspx 
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadData(dummyPageUrl);
```

All this is fine when I run the project in IIS 6 or the Visual Studio built-in web server, however things go crazy in IIS 7 as I get a "System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context".

I am aware of this thread: [Request is not available in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518057/request-is-not-available-in-this-context)

However, I was wondering if anyone had any idea on how to do the above without changing the project to run in classic mode.

Comment: Also, this appears to be a duplicate of the How to get full host name + port number in Application_Start of Global.aspx? question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243270/how-to-get-full-host-name-port-number-in-application-start-of-global-aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access the absolute url of the current request inside Application_Start when running in integrated mode. You could access the virtual path name using `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath` but not an absolute url. Here's [an article](http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart/) which explains a common workaround. As explained in the article you have 2 possibilities:

1. Change your application code to not use the request context (recommended)
2. Perform the initialization in `Application_BeginRequest` using a lock and a singleton to ensure that this initialization is performed only once for the entire lifetime of the AppDomain. Here's a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243338/29407) discussing this second approach.

Comment: ok is there a way of serving a page manually? for example var client = new WebClient(); client.DownloadData(Pages\DummyPage.aspx)

Comment: No, the WebClient method requires an absolute url.

Comment: I see. now the problem in Application_BeginRequest is that once the application is started the _BeginRequest event is not fired until a user lands on any of the pages. That is a problem as I need to hit the page as soon as the application is started.

Comment: But you can't *hit* the page in `Application_Start` because you don't know the address of this page at that stage. Also your application is currently being initialized and you are attempting to trigger requests to it. Seems a wrong approach to me. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to hit this page in Application_Start?

Comment: Correct, but surely there should be a way as this is prefectly possible in iis6 unless it can't be done due to a major architecture change.

Comment: Yes, it can't be done because there's a major architecture change in IIS7. It's called integrated pipeline mode. You could always switch back to the Classic mode in IIS 7 but honestly you are loosing all the benefits if you do so.

Comment: You are right, I will try to see if I can use the _BeginRequest method you suggested. Thanks for your prompt answers.