# get server port from Application_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to be able to fetch the web port being used by my MVC instance on startup, as it may change from site to site. Most answers to how to fetch the port involve getting it from the request object, which doesn't exist in Application_Start. Is there any other way to fetch it?

I tried to fetch it like so:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"]
```

But this throws an exception

> "System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context"

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK this is not possible to be done in `Application_Start` when hosting in Integrated Pipeline mode in IIS 7+. There's a workaround though involving to use `Application_BeginRequest` to do a one time application initialization on the first request only. Checkout the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243338/29407. This answer has been inspired from the [following blog post](http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart).

The other possibility is to of course rethink why you need to know the server port at `Application_Start` and whether you can't do something else.

Comment: Ha! Actually, the reason I need the port is so I can force a request to happen on start, so I can do work that can only happen in Application_BeginRequest :) But thanks for the info!