# Not sure how I can determine my ASP.NET website domain and port, programatically

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, domain-name

In my `global.asax` I'm wiring up some services via `AutoFac` for DI/IoC.

One of these services would like to know the **domain name and port** of the current website.

for example:-

```
builder.RegisterType<AuthenticationService>()
                .As<IAuthenticationService>()
                .WithParameter("localhostServer", new Uri(?????))
                .SingleInstance();
```

this is some configuration stuff.

I have no idea how to pass in the server ip and port, via a new Uri instance when I'm doing this in my `global.asax Application_Start()`

Update: Server == IIS7, integrated mode. (not iis6 or classic mode).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243270/how-to-get-full-host-name-port-number-in-application-start-of-global-aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a sure way to do this:

- IIS can map a number of ips, hostnames and ports to a web application
- Each request can be bound to a different one

You probably need to do one of these things:

- change your code so the binding is only needed when you have a request and not at application start
- if you know the correct value before hand , you can set it by storing it via a configuration key

Comment: Heya :) I was afraid you might suggest those *exact* two options, because that's *exactly* what i've been wracking my brain over, for the last hour :) [With the config suggestion looking like the best thing right now]