# Where is this singleton saving its information?

Tags: asp.net

I am looking at the code presented in this SO answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243338/223742.

The code works exactly as advertised but what I don't understand is how the singleton is storing its static members across requests e.g:

```
private static string host = null;
```

Is it by virtue of the fact that the FirstRequestInitialisation class is static that it is saving it in the storage for the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assertion that it is because the `FirstRequestInitialisation` class is static is correct. Being a static class, it remains in memory for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program resides. This means whenever the 'FirstRequestInitialisation` class is referenced, the same instance is returned across the application, in the same way a static member is shared across all instances of the parent type.

See [Static Classes and Static Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.140).aspx) article on the MSDN for more info.