# Retrieve specific URL fragment from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to retrieve an url specific fragment in a Windows forms application.

I have a WebBrowser Control with an url that redirects on an other URL.
In Navigating procedure, I can read this url and fragments that it contains.
Fragment property is the string with all fragments, but I need one of these.
There is an URL parser that loads all fragments in a dictionary?
Thanks!

Comment: A URL contains only one fragment. Do you mean segments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET - Get protocol, host, and port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640/net-get-protocol-host-and-port)

Comment: @defaultlocale that is not the correct duplicate

Comment: And for the close voter that thinks this belongs on SuperUser.com: No, it belongs here...

Comment: @rene my bad, that's not a duplicate, thank you. I'll vote to reopen if this question gets closed as a dupe. Anyway, the question is still unclear and vague. I was searching for questions about [Uri.Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=vs.110).aspx) and ended up with incorrect dupe