# In ASP.Net applications, can I get which security protocol (SSL3/TLS) the request contains?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, ssl, asmx

I am trying to check from asp.net perspective what security protocol the client is using when trying to interact with my application. I have different applications hosted asp.net web application, asmx webservices, asp.net mvc, wcf services. 
Please suggest me how to know if the request is through ssl/ tls protocol.

My intention is to tell my application users to use tls and not to use ssl3 because of poodle vulnerability.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389899/how-do-i-disable-ssl-fallback-and-use-only-tls-for-outbound-connections-in-net ?

Comment: Yes, I checked this. I want to educate my users not to use it. For this I want to know which protocol is my user requested

Comment: I doubt you have way to extract transport level protocol name as asp.net apis directly deals with higher level protocols like http,https etc.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can interrupt at IIS level to find it?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640/net-get-protocol-host-and-port

Comment: Amit, I wanted to check security protocol ssl/tls...

Comment: I mean authentication protocol for establishing connection between server and client.

Comment: You can't interrupt IIS, but you can certainly disable SSLv3 on IIS itself. Like in one of the top search result for "iis disable sslv3", https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/iis-disabling-ssl-v3.htm

Answer (score 0):

Basically protocal i.e. SSL3 or TSL Doesn't depend on application but mainly depends on the `Framework` they built on . So in your Question i couldn't find the much information about the Framework on which your applications built on.

> My intention is to tell my application users to use tls and not to use
>   ssl3 because of poodle vulnerability.

Your users might be using *your* Webservices or the asmx service that was written and deployed in your server , so i would say that can't ask the user to change their protocal  because its mainly dependent on the framework they are using i.e the framework they built on. so in order to achieve your goal  try to by default make your applications run on `.Net Framework 4.5` and assign to use the `tls` as follows

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192
```

Please find that  Following SecurityProtocalType [Refernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)

```
   Ssl3 = 48,
   Tls = 192,
   Tls11 = 768,
   Tls12 = 3072,
```

In this way instead of telling your Users , you are actually making to use the `tls` when they are requesting your services