# How is the default for ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol derived

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl, tls1.2

I have a VB.NET webforms app that is currently using .NET 4.6 (though it has been repeatedly upgraded since the days of 1.1). I recently ran into a problem where the default value of `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` was `SSL3 or TLS` (I needed TLS 1.2).

It took me a while to find because I assumed the default was based on the .NET version alone (e.g. [this MSDN remark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_2)). When I created a test console app (C#, in VS 2015) the default was `TLS or TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2`.

The target frameworks were the same but the defaults were different (I did search the code base and we are not setting it, so it must be pulling the default). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28333370/295686) states the default for 4 & 4.5, but where in the registry, config file, anything could I update the configuration for the default protocols (WITHOUT having to hard code it in my application)?

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I just saw this question it looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246999/net-why-servicepointmanager-securityprotocol-default-value-is-different-on-dif, the answer stated that default value is decided by Windows version and its patch level