# Why ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol default value is different on different machines?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis

Currently I have an issue and can't find strict answer on it.

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 application targeting 4.6.1 framework and its goal is to work with third party API's that are secured by TLS 1.1/TLS 1.2 protocols.

I have tried to run my application on 2 environments:

- my local machine Windows 10 with .NET 4.6.2 Framework, IIS Express;
- server machine Windows Server 2012 with .NET 4.6.1, IIS 8.0;

The issue is in that when I start it locally `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`  default value is set to `Ssl3, Tls`, so I can't target API's and have to code it on application start to use TLS 1.1/TLS 1.2: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`.

When application runs on server default value `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is set to `Tls, Tls11, Tls12`, so it works well.

According to documentation applications run on .NET Framework 4.6 or above versions have to use TLS 1.1/TLS 1.2 by default, how it is on remote machine.

Why the default values of `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` are different? Is it because .NET Framework configuration? Or maybe registry settings? I have searched through it but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Why does it matter what the *default* value is? If you need some *specific* settings, just setting them anyway would seem like the most straightforward thing to do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This is important because when a server revokes the use of `Ssl3` and `Tls` because they are obsolete, the application that is making the call must have `Tls11` and `Tls12` in the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` to have the newer protocols defined as options that can be used. You can manually specify them in the code, but that is clearly not a good idea. Why wouldn't the most secure versions available be used by default anyway? IMHO, this should've happened without us doing anything...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it matters because hard-coding a specific protocol for each script/app requires more resources to maintain, demanding awareness through turnover and future updates that may not be obvious (especially with opaque Windows SSL/TLS exception messages). In many environments, the reality is that the minimum supported protocol version between systems is periodically raised org-wide, and addressing this at the server scope rather than script-by-script or app-by-app on each server is far easier to manage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[MSDN: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Note that no default value is listed for this property, on purpose. The security landscape changes constantly, and default protocols and protection levels are changed over time in order to avoid known weaknesses. Defaults will vary depending on individual machine configuration, and on which software is installed, and on which patches have been applied.

[MSDN Blogs: Support for SSL/TLS protocols on Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/):

> On Windows the support for SSL/TLS protocols is tied to the SCHANNEL component. So, if a specific OS version doesn’t support a SSL/TLS version, this means it remains unsupported.

[MSDN: Cipher Suites in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Different Windows versions support different TLS cipher suites and priority order. See the corresponding Windows version for the default order in which they are chosen by the Microsoft Schannel Provider.

In other words: this is determined by your Windows version and its patch level.

But like @Damien said, why would you bother what the default level is?

Comment: Thanks for answers guys. I was little confused because of such differences on the similar environments. I've set values explicitly

Answer (score 8):

We can update registry like below to let .Net framework use TLS1.1\TLS1.2, a restart is needed.

I've tried, and the value of ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol in my machine changed from "Ssl3, Tls" to "Tls, Tls11, Tls12":

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: This requires [.NET Framework 4.7.1 or later to use the `SystemDefault` value](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.6-4.7.1#default-value-of-servicepointmanagersecurityprotocol-is-securityprotocoltypesystemdefault), earlier versions of the framework are generally hard-coded defaults, depending on the version.