# .NET framework security protocol

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2

Using

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

The values that i get are Ssl3 | TlS    System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.
I use .NET 4.8 windows 10.
I would expect to see the full list of available TLS protocols ex TLS1, TLS1.1, TLS1.2
Why i get only up to TLS? Where does this information come from?

Comment: Is your _project/solution_ **targeting** `4.8`?

Comment: You should get : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=net-5.0.  You are looking at a different enumeration.  Right click type and the select "definition" to see where it is defined.

Comment: Yes i am targeting 4.8. I get  Ssl3 | TlS in debug from Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the question here
[Why ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol default value is different on different machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246999/why-servicepointmanager-securityprotocol-default-value-is-different-on-different)

I was missing the bellow registry entries:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```