# What is the default ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol value in .NET 4.6.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-4.6

In .NET 4.0 and 4.5, the default value for `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` was `SecurityProtocolType.Tls|SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3` in .NET 4.0/4.5 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28333370/1226755) post.

What is the default value in .NET 4.6.1?  I can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);
}
```

...on 4.6.1 gives the output...

```
Tls, Tls11, Tls12
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  We've got some 4.5 apps that had issues when we turned off TLS1.0 support, so I was curious if upgrading to 4.6 would fix that or if I needed to set the securityprotocol type myself