# How do I create a Web Service Reference to a TLS 1.2 WebService?

Tags: c#, web-services, tls1.2

We just received a message from utah tax authority that they are upgrading their web service to TLS 1.2.

When I tried to create a web service reference to it in visual studio 2010 I got an exception "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'tap.tax.utah.gov'.”

The address is:
https://tapstaging.tax.utah.gov/EFILE/MFET/WSDL/

There does not seem to be anyplace to set what protocol to use when creating a web reference.

Comment: Really? Is it that difficult that no guru on this site knows?

Comment: Well, I tried just downloading the WSDL file and using it to create client code using the instructions at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Generating-a-Web-Service-95ff4e10 but just got a very unhelpful - no code generated error. When I try creating a WCF service reference it tells me that there is an undefined element in the xml but I could not find one (neither could a few xml validation web sites). Maybe I should try Visual Studio 2015? I'll have to wait till I get home for that.

Comment: Well they send me a tiny screen shot from this site and I used it to find this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5 which said to add a registry key enable the protocol. It got me half a step further in that it ALMOST created a web service before telling me it could not create a SSL/TLS secure connection.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it. At least I was able to 'create' the web service. I rebooted my machine and added the registry key to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 node and it seemed to work.

I am forced to use the x86 platform due to my company using very, very old database drivers so that may have been the solution or the reboot, either way I feel a little bit less helpless.

Here are the registry keys from the linked page:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001