# Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream c# Send Email

Tags: c#, email, smtp, certificate, port

The method to send an email is running normally but sometimes it shows this message: `Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.`

It usually occurs when another method which works with a `X509Certificates` certificate is used... the configurations of the email provider are ok.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue yesterday using the code below:

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

This code I found here [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)

I believe that the problem is the framework version, my program is using the 3.5 version...

Thanks