# Issue to use TLS 1.2 in .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2, tls1.2, aaa-security-protocol

I got TLS 1.0 disabled. So we are trying to use TLS 1.2 in our .Net application which is using .Net Framework 4.0.

I have added the code for this at the start

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

It works perfectly on my local system.

But i am not sure why its not working when I deploy the code on server (Windows Server 2008 R2). I checked everything. .Net framework is present on server. But still its giving the same issue on server only.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28333370/213550):

> `.NET 4.0` supports up to `TLS 1.0` while `.NET 4.5` supports up to `TLS 1.2`
>
> However, an application targeting `.NET 4.0` can still support up to TLS 1.2 **if .NET 4.5 is installed in the same environment**. `.NET 4.5` installs on top of `.NET 4.0`, replacing `System.dll`.

So basically you need to upgrade your server to `.Net 4.5` to enable `TLS 1.2`.

Also, you can simplify your code and make it more readable:

```
using System.Net;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Related MSDN articles:

- [`SecurityProtocolType` enum for .Net 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssdf8763(v=vs.100).aspx) (no `Tls12` member here)
- [`SecurityProtocolType` enum for current .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssdf8763(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does this mean, if I have a WinForms application and need TLS 1.2 support for SOAP requests, that I will have to change it to .NET 4.5 and ensure all users have that framework installed?

Comment: Yes, in other way it will not work. If you can do this: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls`, this may do a trick, but still probably will crash as you say you got `TLS 1.0` get disabled.

Comment: SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 doesn't even exist in .NET 4.0 but I can use the int. However it seems there's no way round the fact that users will need .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: Yeah, as been said in referenced answer, you'll get the `NotSupportedException` for `Tls12` value setting for `SecurityProtocol`

Comment: If you want TLS 1.2 without code changes, you really want .NET 4.6 or higher.  True that TLS 1.2 is supported in .NET 4.5, but not enabled as a communication protocol by default until .NET 4.6.  More info here:https://github.com/TheLevelUp/pos-tls-patcher

Comment: It's really not a good idea to hardcode the security protocol in application code. Read [TLS best practices with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) for more info.

Comment: Of course one should move the protocol to config file, it's an example. Not everything should be in system settings

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use TLS 1.2 in existing .NET 4.x code without application code changes, you'll need the following:

1. Install .NET framework 4.6 or higher.  This is needed to use TLS 1.2 as a protocol by default in combination with proper Windows registry keys.
2. Set the following [.NET Framework strong cryptography registry keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-office-online-server#enable-strong-cryptography-in-net-framework-45-or-higher):

On 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`

On 64-bit versions of Windows:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`

The [WOW6432Node](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx) value is used by 32-bit applications when run on a 64-bit system.

For more information see: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/pos-tls-patcher

*Update*:
It's really not a good idea to hardcode the security protocol in application code. You want the OS doing this for you.  See [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) for further reading.

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje yes, if you want IIS to use TLS 1.2.  However, you probably want to look at upgrading to Windows 10 and latest version of IIS and .NET Framework.

Comment: I believe these registry settings are still required then. At least until Microsoft changes them to the be the default behavior which I imagine will eventually happen.

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje, this may also help you: https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto