# Connection Error while consuming the webservice in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.2

I developed a .net web service in .net framework 4.0 and deployed in widows server 2008 R2. Customers are able to consume the web service without any issues. Recently we upgraded the SSL certificate protocol from SSL 3.0 to TLS 1.2. The customers are unable to consume the web service after my protocol upgrade. I gone through some forums i found .net 4.0 doesn't support TLS 1.2 protocol so can anyone suggest the best solution to overcome this without upgrading the .NET framework?

Comment: If you've _restricted_ connections to your service to TLS1.2 then are the consumers/clients that have issues doing likewise (using TLS1.2 to connect)?

Comment: yes, client are facing the issue so reverted back to the protocol to SSL 3.0 but still client want to use the TLS 1.2 secured protocol. @EdSF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue to use TLS 1.2 in .NET Framework 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)

Answer (score 0):

`TLS 1.2` isn't supported by default on `.Net 4.0`, however, you can update your consumers with `.Net 4.5` over the `.Net 4.0`, after that you can use [`TLS 1.2` without any errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42895574/213550):

```
// will not work on .Net 4.0, but will work after update to .Net 4.5
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

If the update is not an option, you have to use two options for `.Net 4.0` - [`SSL 3.0` or `TLS 1.0`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssdf8763(v=vs.100).aspx)