# TLS 1.2 error Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: asp.net, ssl, .net-4.5, tls1.2

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with .Net API using .Net 4.5.2. My API running on the server which has Windows 2008 R2 and I checked in internet properties TLS 1.2 is checked also I have checked from [this link](https://www.howsmyssl.com/s/api.html) and I get `Probably Ok` back. Which means I do have TLS 1.2 enable in my server.

In .Net API I have added below code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

When I try to connect I get following error

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

For testing I started using ASP.net web to integrate with this API and I do get same error but if I change above code to allow all protocols

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
  | SecurityProtocolType.Tls
  | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
  | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I don't get any error and I can connect to my API. Which explains my server not able to establish connection on TLS 1.2. What have I missed here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28286086/213550)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is in the client, not the server. You can see that the [Microsoft blogs suggest](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/) exactly the code you've already use:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

For .Net 4.0 with 4.5 installed on the machine you can use this:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

For earlier version of .Net there are some patches to use the TLS 1.2.

Related questions:

- [Issue to use TLS 1.2 in .NET Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41478506/213550)
- [Connection Error while consuming the webservice in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42844825/213550)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue for payment transactions. Issue resolved with only registry changes and no code change.
Web Instance(Server) is hosted in Microsoft Azure. Used .NET version 4.5. Using payment APIs for BPOINT & PayPal. Following are the registry changes carried out to resolve the issue:

Step 1: Enable TLS1.2 on Client and Server

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f    
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f  
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f    
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f
```

Step 2: Disable TLS1.1 on Client and Server

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f    
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f  
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f    
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
```

Step 3: Enable Strong Cryptography for >NET framework

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319" /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319" /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
```