# Cannot access API via Azure API Management Service by POSTMAN

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman, azure-api-management

I have done following steps

1. Deployed api on server
2. Configure Azure Management Api Service to call api

Now

1. Developer console i can successfully call api via azure api management.
2. Also from C# console, it is called successfully.

But cannot access it via POSTMAN.(It return **404 - File or directory not found**)

Don't know, is it common issue with postman?

Trying to search on google but no help found related to this issue.

Anybody has solution please help.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot access the server in postman (eg 404 Not Found error)?

Comment: @alltej yes it return 404

Comment: I think you have the correct root/base url but the path or url segment is not right. Can you copy the exact URL from the console and paste in POSTMAN?

Comment: @alltej i have added same url that is i obtain from azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using POSTMAN chrome extension, may be due to cross domain request or some proxy issue, It was not working.

After installing window app of POSTMAN.

Using the POSTMAN window app, I am able to access my API.

Still can't find the reason behind the POSTMAN Chrome extension.

**But the window application is working. :)**

Answer (score 0):

It's bit weird. In my case, Postman Chrome's extension works and Windows's App doesn't work. I am still finding the reason.

Comment: Window's app is latest?

Comment: Yes.
This has something to do with the security protocol. I think by default, the setting for Postman Windows's app and Chrome app is different (or perhaps the Chrome one's depend on Chrome browser setting/proxy setting). Until yesterday afternoon, I was not able to connect to Azure APIs. It works as soon as I changed the security protocol. (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12)
More details are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5