# AzCopy error The underlying connection was closed

Tags: .net, ssl, tls1.2, azcopy

I'm getting the following exception while I try to use AzCopy on my prod machine.

```
The underlying connection was closed.
```

Our IT department disabled SSL3,TLS1.0,TLS1.1, only enabled TLS1.2

and because the AzCopy is build with targeting .Net Framework 4.5, app is trying to use SSL3,TLS1.0(which are the default protocol for .Net Framework v4.5).

Is there anyway that I can force the app to use TLS1.2? because only this protocol is enabled on our machine

There is also one solution I think to request from AzCopy team to target >.Net Framework v4.6, because with this version TLS1.2 is added to the default protocols.

Answer (score 0):

AzCopy seems not support to set TLS 1.2 Explicitly. But .Net Framework 4.5 support force by modifying registy. I have tried AzCopy after used following the registry settings, it can actually switched to TLS 1.2:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 – SchUseStrongCrypto = DWORD of 1 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 – SchUseStrongCrypto = DWORD of 1

For more details, please refer to:

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

[Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your answer, I requested this update from IT dep, will write the result when changes are applied.