# How to resolve HTTP Web Request underlying connection was closed error calling API?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, ups

I am trying to validate the zipCode with City using UPS API
"https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/AV".

Below is my code

```
string xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                "<AccessRequest>" +
                "<AccessLicenseNumber>xxxx</AccessLicenseNumber>" +
                "<UserId>xxx</UserId>" +
                "<Password>xxx</Password>" +
                "</AccessRequest>" +
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                "<AddressValidationRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">" +
                "<Request>" +
                "<TransactionReference>" +
                "<CustomerContext>Customer Data</CustomerContext>" +
                "<XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>" +
                "</TransactionReference>" +
                "<RequestAction>AV</RequestAction>" +
                "</Request>" +
                "<Address>" +
                "<PostalCode>" + "38305" + "</PostalCode>" +
                "<City>" + "TENNESSEE" + "</City>" +
                "</Address>" +
                "</AddressValidationRequest>";
                string url = "https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/AV";

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
                //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;


                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlRequest);
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencode";
                req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
//                req.KeepAlive = false;

                //req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
  //              req.UserAgent = "Patoooey";
                Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();                
                requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
                string backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

It works fine on my local machine. but when i deploy it on live server. it gives error
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive._____
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

I have tried setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to TLS, TLS11 or TLS12
but nothing is working on live server.
Also tried request.KeepAlive = false, request.UseDefaultCredentials = true 
and request.UserAgent to "any word greater than 5 char".

Server is running Windows Server Data Center SP2
Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You're sending an XML body with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencode`: maybe the server is rejecting your invalid request?

Comment: Just tried the "application/xml" content type. but still the same issue. it is working fine on my local machine. only giving error on server.

Comment: did u try this `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a,b,c,d) =>  true;`

Comment: Tried but nothing changed.
if i use the line 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
then i get the error underlying connection close
and if i comment the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol
then i get the following error
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

- Even i was facing same issue it was resolved by setting below code
   `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
  .net picks the highest security protocol by default present in your server
- Later for detailed understanding got below reference please refer in case of explanation
  [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)