# When using 3rd party libraries, do they get compiled to the version of my app?

Tags: c#, windows-services, tls1.2

When I include dlls from other projects or 3rd parties, and include them into my VS.NET solution, does it matter what version those libraries were compiled against?

I am targetting version 4.6 in my solution, and I have to make sure all http requests are done using version 4.6 for TLS 1.2

Comment: I'm a little confused by your last paragraph. If your app is using `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` you won't need to worry about compiling a version where that is not available, as you'll get an error. I also don't see how this concern relates to the question in the first paragraph.

Comment: Presumably he/she has a library that makes HTTPS requests, but is unsure if the library will use the SecurityProtocolType default for the runtime version.

Comment: @JimW that is correct.  My app uses another dll and I want to make sure it will also be compiled using the same version when I compile my solution.  A dll is precompiled so I guess not?

Answer (score 0):

What matters is the **runtime** version, not the SDK version you compile with.  So if a library was built against .NET 4.0, but your app is running with runtime 4.5, it will use the v4.5 protocol defaults.

See [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5) for more

EDIT:

If you call

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

then it will apply to the entire application including the library code, unless the library code is explicitly setting SecurityProtocol to some other value.