# RazorPay is not fetching PaymentId using key and secret

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, razorpay

I am implementing an application using AngularJS and Webapi taken two projects in one solution, I used checkout.js in client side then razorpay_payment_id is generating. But in the server side WebAPI application I used

```
string key = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyId"];
string secret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeySecret"];

// Initialize RazorPay Payment Gateway
RazorpayClient client = new RazorpayClient(key, secret);

//Get Payment Using Id
Payment rPayment = client.Payment.Fetch(reservation.PaymentId);
```

Using this `RazorpayClient client = new RazorpayClient(key, secret);` not fetching any *razorpay_payment_id* information.
So that it is showing the error

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

..in razorpay.

I had generated the `keyid` and `keysecret` in test mode.

Why is the razorpayclient information not coming using key and secret?

Comment: can you confirm that key and secret are not null?

Comment: i had given key and secret also, they are not null

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? We are also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I got reply from Razorpay integration support. It's because of incorrect TLS version. Add this line at the top and code would work fine.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192 |
(SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Reference: [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5/28333370#28333370)