# .NET Core Refit HTTPS errors

Tags: c#, .net-core, refit

I have the below code, which uses Refit to make an HTTPS call. It works from a console application targeting the .NET framework 4.6.1.

When I run the exact same code from a console application targeting .NET Core 2.1 I get an error:

> The SSL connection could not be established... An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate

I'm using Refit version 4.5.6

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var baseAddress = new Uri(BaseHttpsAddress);
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress, Timeout = _requestTimeout };

var service = RestService.For<IMyService>(httpClient);

var result = await service.GetUsers();
```

In fact when targeting .NET Core 2.1 all my HTTPS calls fail, but my HTTP calls work fine.

Is there some configuration or something to get HTTPS calls working in a .NET Core 2.1 application using Refit?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to accept all server certificates as valid by the below code.. However in real-time, you add the logic to validate the server certificate.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

....
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; 
...
// your https call goes here
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the ServicePointManager to accept the connections using TLS (appropriate version) protocol. Try *[Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)*. This one is for .NET 4.5. However the same is applicable for .NET Core.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work after adding SecurityProtocol =
                    SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; ... i updated the code in my question

Comment: When i try that it says SSL3 is obsolete and no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

Regular .NET automatically checks the Windows certificates installed and .NET Core doesn't.

So with .NET Core I needed to manually add the certificate and it worked.