# How can I download a specific CSS file in C#?

Tags: c#, web

I'm using `WebClient` and I'm trying to download this CSS file: https://assets.staples-static.com/NC1/pn/bui/20181010140727/styleguide/docs/css/atcOverlay.css

This is the code I tried using:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string css = webClient.DownloadString("https://assets.staples-static.com/NC1/pn/bui/20181010140727/styleguide/docs/css/atcOverlay.css");
```

It didn't work - I got a timeout exception.

Then I tried adding the same headers as the browser:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma, "no-cache");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
webClient.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.9");
string css = webClient.DownloadString("https://assets.staples-static.com/NC1/pn/bui/20181010140727/styleguide/docs/css/atcOverlay.css");
```

Same result.
I even tried replacing `webClient.DownloadString` with `webClient.DownloadData`, and even replace it completely with `HttpWebRequest`. All gave me the same results.

The only differences I see when I use **Fiddler** (I look at the *Raw* tab) are the casing of the `Connection` header (`Keep-Alive` in C# vs. `keep-alive` in browsers), and the order of the headers (which I tried to match as much as I could, but I just can't find a way to put the `HOST` and `CONNECTION` first below the `GET`).

Some other CSS files I try to download from the same host and from other hosts download just fine.

Did anyone encounter such issue? Am I missing anything? What else can I try?

### Update:

I tried Poul Bak's suggestion from comments below. It didn't work. This is the code I used:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "assets.staples-static.com");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
var result = httpClient.GetAsync("https://assets.staples-static.com/NC1/pn/bui/20181010140727/styleguide/docs/css/atcOverlay.css").Result;
```

Comment: Try using 'HttpClient', it's my experience, that it Works much better. (I can't see anything wrong with your code).

Comment: Browsing the  URL directlry from the Browser worked well..

Comment: Have you tried using 'http' instead of 'https' ? It still Works in browser, so...

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you, I tried that. Unfortunately, same results. I'll update the question to show the code I used.

Comment: @PoulBak regarding using `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS` - unfortunately I don't provide the URIs and I don't want to change them in case the server I connect to won't be able to provide them.

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498248/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connectionan-existing-connection-was-for

Comment: @PoulBak I tried `HTTP`, didn't work.

Comment: Well, it was just wild guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests an found a way to make it Work. The problem is the `'Connection'` header value not being set to '`Keep-Alive`'.

So setting that makes it Work:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "assets.staples-static.com");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
    var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://assets.staples-static.com/NC1/pn/bui/20181010140727/styleguide/docs/css/atcOverlay.css");
    string text = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Now I get about 10kb string.

Comment: What about .net 3.5 and 4.0? It seems `HttpClient` is missing in those frameworks, and `WebClient` still doesn't work. Any replacement?

Comment: HttpCient is the replacement for WebClient. May be be you can use HttpWebRequest .