# Windows PowerShell: Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: .net, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am running Windows PowerShell as administrator and I am trying to create a file with information I get from Sharepoint Online. I run the below and get a message with a link I follow (devicelogin), enter the code given and then after I add my credentials, I am signed in.

```
Import-Module PnP.PowerShell
Update-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell*
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://<mydomain>-admin.sharepoint.com" -PnPManagementShell
$siteUrl = "https://<mydomain>.sharepoint.com/sites/ASI-DropPoint"
$cred = Get-Credential
#Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credential $cred 
#or the below to get more detailed info about connection process
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credential $cred -Verbose

$filePath = "C:\Users\ASI_app_eng\Desktop\To do"
$DocLibraryName="Documents"

# testing if the path can be accessed because sometimes I get an error that the access is denied.
if (Test-Path $filePath) {
    Write-Output "It has access"
} else {
    Write-Output "Cannot access the specified file path"
}

# Get the list items from the document library in batches of 1000 items
$listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $DocLibraryName -PageSize 1000

# Create a new file and write the names of the files and last accessed date to it with tab (default) separator 
$listItems | Select-Object Name,LastAccessedDate | Out-File -FilePath "$filePath\filenames.txt"
```

The error I get after some minutes is the below.
Get-PnPListItem : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The library contains almost 7000 documents/items.

I found some information online about the problem [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/authentication-errors-tls12-support), [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/provider-hosted-app-pha-application-errors-tls-errors-and-401/ba-p/2273611)  and on these 2 stackoverflow posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498248/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connectionan-existing-connection-was-for), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5).

I am completely new to PowerShell and Sharepoint management; I practically came up with this script after days of asking chatgpt and solving bug after bug. Are the above solutions suitable for my issue? I am afraid I might do something I'm not supposed to and cause problems to my work laptop and/or sharepoint.

I tried the below, in case it was a connection issue, but this doesn't seem to be the problem. My connection is fast and stable.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credential $cred -RetryCount 3 -RetryWait 10
```