# HttpClient.SendAsyc() returns forbidden in production but returns OK in debug

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Following is the code that i am using. It has been modified slightly for this questions.

```
        var sourcebrandUrl = "https://www.electrolux.se/support/user-manuals/?q=EER77MBM";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, sourcebrandUrl);

        request.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36");
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*",0.8));
        request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-GB",0.9));
        request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-US", 0.9));
        request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en", 0.8));
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request))
        {
                HtmlContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Interestingly the response is OK when I try to debug, but "Forbidden" when I run as production build in the production environment. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

Also the in the base class i am calling the following in constructor 

`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();`

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

---------Edited---------

I found the issue. 
I had to use the following as well

`request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("br"));`

I still do not know why it worked in local debug mode before but not in production mode when it was run in a docker container.

I will appreciate if someone could explain that.

Comment: Just a thought, does the production config have Cors enabled?

Comment: Thank you Trevor. While cors issue  was not related to this problem, but it helped me fix another issue.

Comment: This is .NET or .NET Core, and what version? Does response message contain any hints?

Comment: Check this post as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5