# Intermittent SocketException while trying to contact external web service from Azure web app

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, httpclient

I'm encountering a situation on production that is difficult to debug.
Sometimes the connection to an external service can't be established with the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 93.39.196.220:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

Sometimes it works without any problem. This is what I've tried:

- Replacing the way I perform the connection (from Restsharp to HttpClient)

  - HttpClient is long lived as suggested by [this post](https://www.westerndevs.com/Deployment/httpclientwrong/)
- Adjusting the timeout
- Using async and sync code
- Analyzing SNAT Port exhaustion
  [image: SNAT Connections]

[image: SNAT Failures]

More info:

- The IPs of my server are authorized by the external service (and if they weren't I would be receiving a different error)
- While on production I'm having the problem I'm able to connect to the service from development or staging (so it shouldn't be a problem with the external service)
- While I'm having trouble contacting this service I don't have trouble contacting a different (but similar) service
- I'm on a Web App Service on Azure. I'm using the .NET framework 4.7.2
- The same code sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't

This is (more or less) the current iteration

```
private async Task<ResultSet> SendRequestAsync(HttpClient client, RateRequestBody document){
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync(baseUrl + "/XMLServices", document);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
      ...
    }else{
      ...
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I might have missed?
Thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: No, I ended up proxing the request through an on premise server. This never resulted in the same problem happening again

Answer (score 0):

The answer may lay here: [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)

Assuming both servers are operating correctly, one works fine with your client code and the other gives you problems based on your 'More Info' section: "While I'm having trouble contacting this service I don't have trouble contacting a different (but similar) service"

I recommend removing or commenting out the following line and giving it a try:

```
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

...or replace it with:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try but I have my doubts, as I said the problem is intermittent, so I doubt that the service changes protocol at random intervals, and while it is "down" from production I can still call it (with the same code) from a different environment